# Hidden calling of a function

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say I have two objects, `Master` and `Slave`.

`Slave` has a method named `Init();`. The thing about `Init()` is, that I need it to be virtual, because it contains user's initialization code, but I also need it to get called automatically when the `Slave` is added to `Master`'s List. But the method must not be callable by the user, it has to be automatic.

The first thing that I tried is an event - create an event `SlaveInitialized` that a `Slave` object could handle in its `OnSlaveInitialized` handler. This wouldn't work though, because there's a lot of `Slave` objects and I have no control over the order in which they get created and need to be initialized.

The second thing that I tried is internal method - `internal Init()` would be called when the object is added to `Master`'s list and all seems okay, until I realized that by doing so I cannot inherit the method in a public class.

So the third thing I did and that worked is this - I created an internal method called `_Init()` that simply calls a `protected virtual Init()`, which solved my problem.

---

Now I want to ask - do I just have a major strike of being stupid, because I am missing the painfully obvious solution here, or is this the way it's normally done? What is the proper way? I hope I got the point of what I'm asking across, I tried my best to explain the problem.

Thanks for any help

---

This is the gist of the code I now have. Its point is to have Init() invisibly and automatically called when you add any Slave object to the Master's list via Master.AddSlave();

```
public class Master
{
    private List<Slave> _slaves;

    public void AddSlave(Slave slave)
    {
        // Call the "hidden" init
        slave._Init();
        _slaves.Add(slave);
    }
}

public class Slave
{        
    internal void _Init()
    {
        // Call the topmost overloaded method.
        Init();
    }

    protected virtual void Init()
    {

    }
}

public class SuperSlave : Slave
{        
    protected override void Init()
    {
        // Now this method gets called automatically
        // when Master.AddSlave adds this object.
    }
}
```

Comment: Small snippets of code of what you tried are a lot more helpful than a description.

Comment: "But the method must not be callable by the user" and "I need it to be virtual, because it contains user's initialization code" are probably incompatible statements, insomuch as I can't think of any way for the user to provide you with a method implementation that they themselves cannot call.

Comment: You add code to the virtual function, but you have no control over actually invoking it, it's done automatically when the Slave should be initialized - that's what I mean. I'll edit the question and post some code snippets shortly.

Comment: To add to my comment above, if you loosen the requirement to "I need it to be virtual, because it contains user's initialization code, and I don't *expect* the user to call it themselves, instead I want the Master class to call it" then the answer becomes much easier.

Comment: Can't master just call slave's Init() in whenever master adds slave to the list?

Comment: "Let's say I have two objects, Master and Slave." Then I hope you're not writing software [for Los Angeles county.](http://www.snopes.com/inboxer/outrage/master.asp) ;)

Comment: Is this to prevent `Init` from being called twice (by accident)?  I think a better option than preventing someone from calling `Init` is to write documentation explaining what it is used for.  You shouldn't have to prevent the user from writing bad code so long as you explain how the object works and it conforms to typical guidelines.

Comment: Matthew: Yes, basically - I am looking for automated solution that no one can fool around with.

Comment: Dan J: Haha, I had no idea about that. It just seemed right to clearly state what is dependent on what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there are two basic ways to do this.

1. Like you already tried, an `internal InitInternal()` method that calls a `protected virtual Init()`
2. A `protected internal virtual Init()`, which outside of your assembly automatically becomes a `protected` method.

Answer (score 1):

While this doesn't answer the question the way you might want it, however I feel this could be an approperiate solution.

I would recommend throwing an [InvalidOperationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception.aspx) if the `Init` method gets called multiple times.

Description: *The exception that is thrown when a method call is invalid for the object's current state.*

In my opinion it should not be your responsibility to police your objects from being abused, so long as documentation is written properly, your objects properties and method names describe what they do, it should be enough for most users (developers) consuming your code to understand how it works.

For those who decide to call `Init` themselves and then add to the `Master` object, you can throw that exception so they will know that their method for using the class is incorrect.

EDIT:
Naming the method `OnInit` might be a good idea, that way the user of the class has an indication that it should not be directly called by themselves.

Comment: I will combine both of these approaches, i.e. have the hidden internal method call the other one and in case     Init is called again, throw and exception. Thanks to both of you